# R: Error in tseries::garch() Function for Auto GARCH Model Detection

Tags: r, time-series, arch

I am trying to obtain the best `GARCH` model for a simulated series.

```
# simulate a time series.
tts <- arima.sim(100, model = list(ar = c(-.8), order = c(1, 0, 0)))

# obtain best `GARCH` model for the seies.
tseries::garch(tts, order = c(1, 1), grad = "numerical", trace = FALSE)
```

**Problem**

I got this error:

> Error in if (object$p != 0 || object$q != 0) { :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

**What I Want**

1. How do I fix this error?
2. Is there alternative method to obtain `auto-garch` model other than what I demonstrated above?